# Freezer stopped working while fermenting

Tags: fermentation

So I just finished 2 - 5 gallon batches yesterday and I go to check on them today and my freezer stopped cooling. I can hear water running inside the walls but it doesn't get cool. It's about 75 F inside the freezer currently.

Any ideas on how to cool the inside down temporarily? I would like to leave them in the freezer since it's dark and the temperature would be stable but I might have to remove them if I can't get it cooler.

Comment: Put ice in it. Freezing plastic bottles of water is one way to do it that won't create a mess when the ice melts. Your freezer essentially becomes a picnic cooler.

Answer (score 2):

Start freezing 2L bottles of water.  Depending on the size of your fermentation freezer and the external ambient temp, you might be able to amble through using those and treating it like one really big beach cooler.
Other than that the compressor or the coolant lines need replacing/repair; which normally isn't done the whole unit is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of frozen 2 liter bottles (I actually use 1 liter bottles), then those are great,

Otherwise, run to the store and get bags of ice. Leave the ice in the bag. Yes, there will be condensation, water, etc, but you will get the freezer chilled.

Do not place the frozen items against the fermentor(s).

NOTE: Do not add massive amounts of frozen objects, unless you will be monitoring the temp closely. You do not want to let the yeast go to sleep or go into shock.

A chest freezer should hold the temp for a long time, so you should be safe with a small amount of frozen/cold items. A non-chest freezer will lose the chill every time the door is opened, to bear that in mind.